# How to make a text area transparent in Xcode OS X using swift

Tags: macos, swift

I am trying to make a `NSTextView` transparent I have done this before in **Objective-C** but I can't figure out how to make it work in swift.

Sorry for not posting things I have tried but I have tried a lot of different things and I can't find an answer anywhere. Thank you in advanced for any answers

Comment: Actually, it's so similar. Why don't you just handle it by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike UITextView (iOS) NSTextView does not have an alpha property.

If you set the view's wantsLayer property to true, you should be able to set it's layer's alpha value to 0 to make it transparent.

Answer (score -1):

i havent tryed it but this should work, textView.alpha = 0.1
this has transparency of 10%

Comment: I get 'NSTextView' does not have a member named 'alpha' from it i might be doing it wrong I'm honestly pretty new with Xcode

Comment: @user4905499 do you want the background transparent or the TextField itself?

Comment: Unlike iOS, NSView objects don't have an alpha property. (I didn't notice that this was an OS X question at first either.)

Comment: I want the text field transparent but the background would work to